# Input format for AffinityPropagation clustering

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I was using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` method using a precomputed affinity matrix:

Here is the code generating that upper triangular matrix:

```
distances = np.zeros((len(reprs), len(reprs))) * -1
for i, j in it.combinations(range(len(reprs)), 2):
    distances[i][j] = (reprs[i] - reprs[j])**2
```

I can also represent it compactly:

```
distances = distances[np.triu_indices(len(reprs), 1)]
```

Now I wanted to try `sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation` instead, but I can't figure out how to send affinity matrix:

```
def affinity_cluster(distances):
    ap = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(preference="precomputed")
    d = ap.fit_predict(???)
```

From it's [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html#sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.fit):

> fit(X)
>       Create affinity matrix from negative euclidean distances, then apply affinity propagation clustering.
>       Parameters :
>
> ```
> X: array [n_samples, n_features] or [n_samples, n_samples] :
>     Data matrix or, if affinity is precomputed, matrix of similarities / affinities.
> ```
>
> fit_predict(X, y=None)
>       Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.
>       Parameters :
>
> ```
> X : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>     Input data.
>
> Returns : 
>
> y : ndarray, shape (n_samples,)
>     cluster labels
> ```

So, they are expecting a tuple of two elements, but I have an M*N matrice or a vector of M*N/2 elements.

So, how can I use `sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropogation` with an affinity matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a square, symmetric matrix. `array [n_samples, n_samples]` should be read `array of shape (n_samples, n_samples)`. I'll fix the docs in a minute.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great library, and it's helping me tremendously on my graduation project. Also I'm trying to use it for converting my professors from MATLAB to Python. 

Will accept the answer when I have time to try.